# PyTorch Lightning Trainer Error: 'val_dataloader' must be implemented

Tags: pytorch-lightning

```
<ipython-input-16-c4a9c8551282> in on_validation_epoch_end(self)
    167 
    168     def on_validation_epoch_end(self):
--> 169         print(self.val_dataloader())
    170         ppl, nll, elbo, rec, kl, mi, au = calc_all(self, self.val_dataloader())
    171         self.log("val_ppl", ppl)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/hooks.py in val_dataloader(self)
    469             implement this method.
    470         """
--> 471         raise MisconfigurationException("`val_dataloader` must be implemented to be used with the Lightning Trainer")
    472 
    473     def predict_dataloader(self) -> EVAL_DATALOADERS:

MisconfigurationException: `val_dataloader` must be implemented to be used with the Lightning Trainer
```

How to fix this?

I tried to implement `val_dataloader` to the class, but it can't solve it.

Comment: Hi Brian, did you manage to solve your problem or find a workaround? I am getting the same error on the test_dataloader even though I added it to my DataModule. Cheers